# How to run a function with nested function for another folder in Python

Tags: python, function, directory, nested

I have a func_2 nested in func_1, and they perform things in different directories. My current directory is the directory for func_2. I am iterating over the filename in the directory of func_1, but func_2 is performed in a different folder, what should I do?

```
directory = 'directory of a childfolder containing all the ".pdb" files needed in filename'
def func_1(Chain_1):
  index_1 = 0
  for filename in os.listdir(directory): # filename(str)
    if filename.endswith(".pdb"):
      scores = []
      if index_1 <= 10:
        temp = func_2(Chain_1, filename) # func_2 execute a .cpp file in the mother folder
        scores.append(temp)
        index_1 = index_1 + 1
    else:
      continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the working directory whenever you enter your function.

This can be done with the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

```
import os

# get the current working directory
print(os.getcwd())

# change the current working directory
os.chdir('./some/existing/folder')

# current working directory is now the new path
print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: But the problem is: filename is got from the child folder, while the func_2 should be performed in the mother folder. filename is an input for func_2.

Comment: Why don't you `os.chdir('motherfolder')` directly befor calling `func_2` and change back to `os.chdir('childrenfolder')` directly after `func_2`?

Comment: I tried it and didn't quite work. It returns error: cannot sparse file "xxxx.pdb"

Comment: You might need to adjust the `filename` paths so that they are relative to the folder used in `func_2`. You can switch the folder upwards by adding `"/../"` to the path.